# Is Breast augmentation haram after breastfeeding?

Tags: fatwa

Alsalamu Alikum. I have a question regarding breast augmentation. After having kids and breastfeeding my breasts lost volume and look deflated and saggy. My breasts have been always very small and always made me have low self esteem and caused distress. I know getting implants to enlarge them is haram. My question is, am I allowed to have fat transfer to them with a lift so they are not saggy and some volume is put back after losing the volume and losing breast tissue due to breast feeding?. With fat transfer, fat gets reabsorbed eventually and doesn’t really add much volume anyway, not like an implant. I’m not trying to get my breast bigger, Im trying to fix the lost breast tissue and the saggyiness. My husband is ok with my body and satisfied and is not asking me to enlarge my breasts. I’m doing this for my self image and self esteem and correcting what pregnancy and breast feeding did. Now, transferring fat could cause my breast to go half a cup bigger initially, and it might get reabsorbed later. Fat transfer is unpredictable and not worth it for small breasts bcz it doesn’t add noticeable volume. But I would be so happy if I can get rid of the saggyiness and the deflated look by adding some fat. Is it permissible or is it haram? Jazakum Allah Khair.